# Managing my manager's friend

Tags: nepotism

Every time I have an issue with this employee, I get what I believe is biased feedback and the employee seems to not be too concerned about bending rules feeling protected by my manager.

How can I effectively manage an employee who is a good friend of my manager?

Comment: This is going to depend a *lot* on context.  What sort of a person is your manager?  How close a friend are they?  Is the employee generally a good employee, or generally terrible?  Details matter, here.

Comment: Have you talked about this with your manager? Does your manager really protect this employee, or just this employee feels protected? If you feel this is worth it, there are certainly ways you can take it above your manager or to HR.

Comment: I don't read anything in your question that would prevent you from just treating them like any other employee (their own beliefs about them being protected is just that - their own belief, don't make it yours). Has your manager actually done anything to prevent or undermine your attempts to manage the employee?

Answer (score 6):

> How can I effectively manage an employee who is a good friend of my
>   manager?

This is a tough spot for you to be in.

The answer to this is to *document, document, document*.  Anytime the employee steps out of line you need concrete documentation as to what was done wrong and how you expect similar situations to go in the future.

Even then, at some point *you need to learn if your manager is going to allow you to manage this employee fairly*.  Your manager **may** directly or indirectly continue to protect their friend and it will be **very** difficult for you to overcome.

You may have some hard decisions to make soon.

Comment: +1 for document everything.  The manager may not know what his friend is up to, and they may not be all that close.

Comment: Another reason to document everything is: If this employee somehow screw something, his first manager (Guessing taking in mind the question) is you, so if something happen they will ask first to you and better to have some records of what happened...